# Trying to use boost lambda, but my code won't compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-lambda

I am trying to use boost lambda to avoid having to write trivial functors.
For example, I want to use the lambda to access a member of a struct or call a method of a class, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::lambda;

vector< pair<int,int> > vp;

vp.push_back( make_pair<int,int>(1,1) );
vp.push_back( make_pair<int,int>(3,2) );
vp.push_back( make_pair<int,int>(2,3) );

sort(vp.begin(), vp.end(), _1.first > _2.first );
```

When I try and compile this I get the following errors:

```
error C2039: 'first' : is not a member of 'boost::lambda::lambda_functor<T>'
        with
        [
            T=boost::lambda::placeholder<1>
        ]
error C2039: 'first' : is not a member of 'boost::lambda::lambda_functor<T>'
        with
        [
            T=boost::lambda::placeholder<2>
        ]
```

Since vp contains `pair<int,int>` I thought that _1.first should work.  What I am doing wrong?

Comment: lambda gets a little complicated when using member functions of placeholders.  You have to bind member method to placeholder (there is an example in documentation).  However alternative is to write accessor, e.g. `first(_1) > second(_2)` which is a little bit cleaner in my opinion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is something akin to:

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp> // new header

// typedefs make code easier
typedef pair<int,int> pair_type;
typedef vector<pair_type> vector_type;

vector_type vp;

vp.push_back( make_pair(1,1) ); // don't specify template arguments!
vp.push_back( make_pair(3,2) ); // the entire point of make_pair is
vp.push_back( make_pair(2,3) ); // to deduce them.

sort(vp.begin(), vp.end(),
        bind(&pair_type::first, _1) > bind(&pair_type::first, _2) );
```

Comment: I like your point with the typedefs, but you're still repeating the <int, int> a lot.  You can do `vp.push_back( vector_type::value_type(1,1) );` to make future maintenance easier (only one line to change if you want to use longs instead).

Comment: @Tim: Oops, I didn't even consider that code, that's just copy-paste. I would do...this. (Edit.)

Comment: The trouble with `make_pair` is that if it's alright with `int` try having a `vector< std::pair<float,float> >` and you'll have to precise `f` near each of your figures... argument deduction is messy with numerics :/

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#member_functions_as_targets), I believe the syntax is

```
sort(vp.begin(), vp.end(), 
bind(&pair<int,int>::first, _1) > bind(&pair<int,int>::first, _2));
```

However, I'd like to point out the (not so?) obvious -- `sort(vp.begin(), vp.end());` will basically do the same thing. `pair`s are by default sorted by their first argument, then by the second. Since you're using `sort` (which is not stable), you're going to have all the pairs sorted by `first`, and then the pairs with equal `first` are going to be in more or less random order.

If you want to preserve the order when the first elements are equal, you should use `stable_sort` instead.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. (Regarding pair - I had just it to simplify the code)

Comment: I had a feeling this was just an example, but I wanted to make sure :)